# truncate the value to a specific character

Tags: formula

How do I write the values from the email field only after the @ symbol into the custom lead field ? which formula should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with several different methods, the most obvious candidates being RIGHT or MID.

```
RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - FIND('@', Email))
```

Or:

```
MID(Email, FIND('@', Email) + 1, LEN(Email))
```

Where:

- `RIGHT(String, Length)` takes the last Length characters from a String
- `MID(String, Start, Length)` takes the characters from the Start, for Length characters, from the String
- `FIND(SearchString, SourceString)` finds the first index of SearchString in SourceString.
- `LEN(String)` returns the number of characters in the String

Comment: спасибо, сработало!)

Comment: @ArtemPaderin пожалуйста (I hope I got this right)

Comment: N.B. if the email field is Shield Platform encrypted, this won't work as RIGHT and MID can't be used on encrypted fields